# AWS Cognito in react js with django rest framework?

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to integrate third party authentication with AWS Cognito in my webapp.
I have a React JS app with a django backend.

I found [this](https://djangostars.com/blog/bootstrap-django-app-with-cognito/) tutorial but I dont really get how this will work with an existing frontend application rather than how to implement it.

if a user logs into the frontend and is authenticated via cognito (other question: is a backend in Amplify necessary?), can the token be passed to the django API - does cognito then need to be called again in django? this step is not yet completely clear to me.

Any help is appreciated. Are there no examples for react + DRF?

Comment: I answered your question. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you @hithacker I accepted your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial that you read shows the correct way to implement it on the backend. In your react frontend, you will use Amplify to get the token. When you are making an API call from your React API, pass the token to your API via the HTTP header `Authorization` with the value `Bearer <access_token>`.

Comment: I am working on a similar project, React + Django + Congnito, question on your reply above is after login and get token from Congito React FE  calls django api to pass token, and how django verify/authenticate this token?

Comment: I followed this tutorial to set up the django part: https://djangostars.com/blog/bootstrap-django-app-with-cognito/